# docker won't start on boot, ports are open w/o process

Tags: systemd, docker

Using docker 20.10.2 under Ubuntu 20. Deploying a stack w/ docker-compose.

When I reboot the host, no container starts automatically even though they have a `restart: unless-stopped` and `restart: always` set.

The strange thing, that when I attempt to manually re-deploy the stack (`docker-compose up -d`), I get a bunch of `bind` errors:

```
Creating influxdb    ... error
 starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:8053: bind: address already in use
Creating portainer   ... error

ERROR: for influxdb  Cannot start service influxdb: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint influxdb (c96dbf129ad4c7c1e4ffe01a281f680a0174b277c9364ae8de41d864444319f4): Error startingCreating mariadb     ... error
WARNING: Host is already in use by another container

ERROR: for portainer  Cannot start service portainer: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint portainer (c19930b176b21051089da6b6eb14c225d74a6bed867ab42bd23b61a81be794d8): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:9000: bind: address already in use
WARNING: Host is already in use by another container

ERROR: for mariadb  Cannot start service mariadb: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint mariadb (184e22f74c14126e8c5d4129e4a609b11f102ffcee9612c941e519f12e92d708): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:3306: bind: address already in use
Creating traefik     ... error

ERROR: for traefik  Cannot start service traefik: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint traefik (ddb84136d437d378547c39bceef5b06e169f2f72936cf092bd025b84eb7fc357): Error starting us
```

`netstat` does show them as used, but they seem to be unattached to any process

```
$ netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6443            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9229            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
$ lsof -i:3306
$ ps -p 3306 -o comm=
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
$
```

I'm not seeing anything interesting in `journal -xab`, except these:

```
Jan 21 22:20:04 hassvm systemd[1]: run-docker-runtime\x2drunc-moby-e3aa5cd3fb4175c7b46de9d5dcd412b2baffa516a29afbd83dd727791e2cfbac-runc.V7HkWR.mount: Succeeded.
-- Subject: Unit succeeded
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- The unit run-docker-runtime\x2drunc-moby-e3aa5cd3fb4175c7b46de9d5dcd412b2baffa516a29afbd83dd727791e2cfbac-runc.V7HkWR.mount has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
Jan 21 22:20:04 hassvm systemd[4337]: run-docker-runtime\x2drunc-moby-e3aa5cd3fb4175c7b46de9d5dcd412b2baffa516a29afbd83dd727791e2cfbac-runc.V7HkWR.mount: Succeeded.
-- Subject: Unit succeeded
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- The unit UNIT has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
Jan 21 22:20:10 hassvm systemd[1]: run-docker-runtime\x2drunc-moby-efb800957288657eb83568a3cf9c6669fc3c1c7782e678effa01f4c4f4d5a21a-runc.TpI8YC.mount: Succeeded.
-- Subject: Unit succeeded
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- The unit run-docker-runtime\x2drunc-moby-efb800957288657eb83568a3cf9c6669fc3c1c7782e678effa01f4c4f4d5a21a-runc.TpI8YC.mount has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
Jan 21 22:20:10 hassvm systemd[4337]: run-docker-runtime\x2drunc-moby-efb800957288657eb83568a3cf9c6669fc3c1c7782e678effa01f4c4f4d5a21a-runc.TpI8YC.mount: Succeeded.
-- Subject: Unit succeeded
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- The unit UNIT has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
```

No idea what it means though.

Nothing changes when I restart the docker service (`sudo systemctl restart docker.service`).
Only works when I restart the socket (`sudo systemctl restart docker.socket`)

What's going on? It there a permanent solution for this?

Comment: Is a firewall running ie  `ufw` which is blocking ports? Is `apparmor` activated.which could block as well. Check `systemctl status ufw apparmor` or whatever is running, turn it off and retest.

Comment: `ufw` was indeed running, `apparmor` was not. disabling `ufw` didn't help. any other idea?

Comment: Is ufw turned off? Check output of `systemctl status ufw` If not stop it `systemctl stop ufw`. `systemctl disable ufw` and reboot. Then try again

Comment: @MichaelD. Yes `ufw` stopped and disabled. Though I'm not sure how would a FW keep ports open in netstat

Comment: Is `snapd` running `systemctl status snapd` which does similar container things? Disable or uninstall it if not needed. Is the machine running on bare metal or is it a VM?

Comment: `snapd` was running. Disabling it did not affect. The system is a VM on top of Proxmox which is running on a NUC8. Why does it matter?

Comment: could be the vm network adapter configuration or the host systems firewall.

Comment: If that was the case, how is running `systemctl restart docker.socket` on the VM fixes the issue? What is strange in my eyes is that the ports are already "taken" by the VM itself.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I have a similar issue on Ubuntu where the docker daemon is not honoring the proxy after a reboot unless I restart docker.socket manually

Answer (score 1):

In my case this was caused because both the apt and snap version of docker was installed. I removed the snap version of docker by running `sudo snap remove docker`

After a reboot docker containers started up again and the the proxy setting which I had configured for the daemon worked as well.

Comment: Probably wise to steer clear of these newer packaging schemes, especially where they aren't absolutely necessary.

Comment: I aggree, however it is not always obvious. In my case I selected docker should be installed when installing ubuntu, which caused docker to be installed via snap.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a problem of docker networking, while I was connected to a VPN. The command o/p suggests to look at `journal -xe` , which isn't really useful, as the OP has already pointed out. Useful logs were found in `/var/log/syslog` which complained about `dockerd` not being able to list network controllers. For some, it complains about some other errors like not being able to connect etc.

When I disconnected from the VPN, the docker daemon service started cleanly.